# Setting a Time Limit on Apps

Tags: permissions, lock

With online school, working productively online is a big focus for me right now. I was wondering if there was a way, whether through a program or code I could lock some of my apps so I can't use them from [TIME AM] to [TIME PM].

Comment: Anything you can lock, you can also unlock. If you have sudo permission, you can trivially override any user lock. The machine is your servant; it cannot be your parent.